# How to retrieve Creation Date of Azure.Storage.Blobs Item

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-explorer

I am trying to delete a blob if it has been created(cannot be modified) 7+ days earlier so I need to
know when the file has been created.
When I saw that not only `blobItem.Properties.LastModified` but also `blobItem.Properties.CreatedOn`
was nullable I started googeling.
I read that even CreatedOn is not really set when I upload a blob. ( I am using `DataLakeFileClient.UploadAsync` for that)

Still Azure Storage Explorer shows DateModified in Blop Properties but it's not accessible:

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(StorageConnectionString);
            var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobItems = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
            await foreach (var blobItem in blobItems)
            {
                if (blobItem.Properties.CreatedOn.HasValue)
                {
                   
                }
                else
                {  // always end up here
        }
```

So I tried to set MetaData in Storage Explorer but I cannot read them either:

```
        _logger.LogInformation(string.Join(';',blobItem.Metadata.Keys));
```

Strangely they also disappear in Storage Explorer once they have been saved.

Any ideas how to workaround these issues?

Comment: Are you basically trying to build lifecycle management? ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: yes :D I already came across something similar but that was not quite what I was looking for. But the linked article looks quite promising :)

Comment: Always better to use what is there then to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @yBother,  which storage are you using? [general purpose v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#types-of-storage-accounts) or [data lake storage v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction), or others? I see you're using `DataLakeFileClient.UploadAsync` to upload a file, so I want to confirm which storage you're using.

Comment: data lake storage! would also ScheduleDeletion() be an option? I could use it like                 await fileClient.ScheduleDeletionAsync(new DataLakeFileScheduleDeletionOptions(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), DataLakeFileExpirationOrigin.Now));
is that billable? LifceCycleManagement rules are free.

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot repro this issue for Azure Data Lake storage gen2. You'd better use the latest version of Storage Explorer, or it's just a temp issue.

It is always recommended to use [lifecycle management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal) to delete blobs after a specified period.

And for `fileClient.ScheduleDeletionAsync(new DataLakeFileScheduleDeletionOptions(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), DataLakeFileExpirationOrigin.Now));`, its pricing is the same as [lifecycle management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal), you only need to pay the cost by writing operation, the delete operation is free(this code is actually used [Set Blob Expiry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-expiry) in the backend, which will set the file's `ExpiresOn` property). Here is the screenshot of the [ADLS Gen2 pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/data-lake/):

[image]

By using this code, you can control the time for deletion which is better than `lifecycle management`. But you should manage your code / environment by yourself.